# How to implement interactive symbol dragging with mapbox-gl on flutter

Tags: flutter, porting, mapbox-gl

Using ***mapbox-gl v0.11.0*** on ***flutter v2.0.6*** (targeting *iOS* & *Android*) I want to programmatically track the lat/long of a *Symbol* as a user drags it. I'm looking for a Flutter example corresponding to creating a *SymbolManager()* with a drag listener on native Android Mapbox SDK. I want continuous tracking so I can interactively show the  distance along a road (not just the absolute dragged distance) as the user is dragging.

###### I'm looking for Flutter mapbox-gl apis corresponding to the following ones from native Android Mapbox SDK

```
private val symbolDragListener = object : OnSymbolDragListener {
    override fun onAnnotationDragStarted(annotation: Symbol) {...}
    override fun onAnnotationDrag(annotation: Symbol) {...}
    override fun onAnnotationDragFinished(annotation: Symbol) {...}
}

symbolManager = SymbolManager(mapView, mapboxMap, style);
symbolManager.addDragListener(symbolDragListener)
```

Comment: have you defined some solution? I am looking the same(

Comment: My workaround is using MapboxMapController.onSymbolTapped.add(myCallback1) to replace drag start and MapboxMap(onMapLongClick: myCallback2) to trigger my previous drag finished operation.